# Display UITableView row (set bounds) at end of the Table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am implementing a UITableViewController for an iOS application. The last row (cell) performs a "delete" function, so I want it to appear at the end of the view. How do I set the start co-ordinates (bounds) of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the placement of UITableViewCells through their coordinates. The UITableView takes complete control of their placement. The only thing you can do is control the order and height of the cells through the table view delegate and data source. If you want a view to always appear at the bottom of the table, you can set that view to be the tableFooterView of the UITableView.